# How to setup custom not found page when using java based container configuration?

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to setup a Spring 4.1.7 MVC application using WebApplicationInitializer. The problem is that when my users try to hit a page for which no mapping is present, they get a tomcat 403 page. I get `PageNotFound:1136 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI <my URI> in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'`.

I don't want to use web.xml and can't find anything related to setting up custom 403 page. Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message you have provided, I believe you would want to add:

```
ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(<your root context here>));
servlet.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound", "true");
```

while overriding `onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)` method provided by spring's WebApplicationInitializer interface (Servlet registration line is just provided for clarity).

Then you'll also need to add an [exception handler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-controller-advice) method and handle NoHandlerFoundException provided by Spring web.